# Best practice for handling user names in notifications in DB

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I would like to create a notification document on Firebase (Cloud Firestore) which includes a "sender" display name (eg. Anonymous128 sent you a message). This name is prone to changing.

What is the best practice to dynamically update the name if it does change? Should I just store userId, and pull the name up every time I'm querying notifications from the database? Or would it be better to update all notifications belonging to a user if they change their display name?

Thanks!

Comment: Which of the two happens more frequently? If reading notifications is much more frequent than a user updating their name, then I'd recommend storing sender's name in notification documents as that'll save you plenty of read operations that'll you'll spend on fetching user's name everytime. Usually there's some rate limit on changing user name so even if a user has sent a lot of notifications that shouldn't cost a lot.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Why not answer the question with that info?

Answer (score 1):

If reading notifications is much more frequent than a user updating their name, then I'd recommend storing sender's name in notification documents as that'll save you plenty of read operations that'll you'll spend on fetching user's name every time.

This does mean that you'll have to update plenty of documents when a user updates their name. Usually there's some rate limit to change user name so this operation should not be much frequent. Also the term *notification* seems like you'll be deleting the document after the receiver has read the message. If yes, then the update costs should reduce too.

---

Alternatively, you just store `userId` in notifications documents. When you fetch all the notifications of current user, parse an array of *unique userIds* from them and then query senders' documents. This ensures you fetch document of each user only once and not for every notification they have sent. Additionally, you can cache these usernames like `{ uid: "name" }` locally and periodically clear that.